# how do I loop through nextToken

Tags: python-3.4, boto3

I just kind of figured out how to use the nextToken in boto3. The API call I am  making I should expect about 300 entries.  I only get 100. I know I need to loop through the next token but I am struggling on how to do that. I am new to the python army.

```
def myservers():

  response = client.get_servers(maxResults=100,)
  additional = client.get_servers(nextToken=response['nextToken'])
```

this little snipit will give me the first 50 plus the first 'nextToken' for a total of 100 items. Clearly I need to iterate over and over to get the rest. I am expecting 300 plus items.

Answer (score 8):

I would just do a simple `while` loop:

```
response = client.get_servers()
results = response["serverList"]
while "NextToken" in response:
    response = client.get_servers(NextToken=response["NextToken"])
    results.extend(response["serverList"])
```

Comment: saved me an hour

Comment: doesn't work if first page does not have a NextToken, but since OP says 300 results in that particular case, then yes.

Comment: "doesn't work if first page does not have a NextToken" <-- it should. what's happening in your case?

Answer (score 2):

I used the suggestion here:

https://github.com/boto/botocore/issues/959#issuecomment-429116381

You have to keep calling client.get_servers() passing in the NextToken.

Comment: Thanks, this gives more pythonic feel :)

Answer (score 2):

Derived from the [answer @Luke mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55333258/893350), here is a simple method to call any method using the `nextToken`

```py
def get_all_boto_records(method, args_dict, response_to_list):
    all_records = []
    extraArgs = {**args_dict}

    while True:
        resp = method(**extraArgs)

        all_records += response_to_list(resp)
        if "nextToken" in resp:
            extraArgs["nextToken"] = resp["nextToken"]
        else:
            break
    return all_records
```

Here is how to use it:

```
all_log_records = get_all_boto_records(
    client.filter_log_events,
    {
        "logGroupName": "",
        "filterPattern": "",
    },
    lambda x: x["events"],
)
```

Another great example with another method to get the log groups

```py
all_log_groups = get_all_boto_records(
    client.describe_log_groups,
    {"logGroupNamePrefix": f"/aws/lambda/{q}"},
    lambda x: x["logGroups"],
)
```